# Why POD file cannot import target project header files in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, header-files, podfile

I'm using PODS and modify them as well. I came to encounter a situation where I need a POD file say PODTest to import file TargetTest.h which is main target header file. I checked if target files can import header files but not vice versa. I could write below line with no compilation error in POD file.

```
@class TargetTest;
```

But properties created for TargetTest cannot be used in POD file PODTest.h or PODTest.m

AM i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

project->build settings->User Header Search Paths and add ${SRCROOT} choose recursive.

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: It is already there. Still not able to find any header file from main project.

Comment: From the issue navigator, this error stands under "Lexical or Preprocessor issue"